# My SQlite is too slow to return something, is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

I have a desktop application that use SQlite3 as the internal memory. The database has now 3GBs and about 5.1M registers in Costumer table and I don't know in the Purchase table.

Problem:
Every time a start my program, it's needs to take all the Customers that bought something in the day or not paid yet some part or comes in the day. the query is :

```
SELECT * FROM Costumers JOIN Purchase ON Costumers.id = Purchase.id WHERE needsPay != alreadyPaid OR dataIn > 12321 OR dataBought > 12321 ORDER BY Account, id, purchaseId;
```

The tables created was:

```
CREATE TABLE Costumers  ( account TEXT, name TEXT, cellNumber TEXT, dataIn REAL, 
                            dataBought REAL, type INTEGER, needsPay INTEGER,
                             alreadyPaid INTEGER, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID

CREATE TABLE Purchase ( purchaseId INTEGER, 
                        dateDone REAL, qtProducts INTEGER,
                        price REAL, purchaseOrigin INTEGER, costumerId INTEGER, 
                        UNIQUE (purchaseId, costumerId), 
                        FOREIGN KEY(costumerId) REFERENCES Costumers(costumerId) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I already tried:

Create index to the columns used;
Change the 'or's for union;
Without the order by.

The main problem is even a simple 'select * from Customers' takes about 400 seconds.

Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: Don'tt use without rowid when your PK is a single integer column... Use a normal rowid table.

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html and https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html and https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html which all together should give you some approaches to explore.

Comment: @Shawn thanks a lot, I'm gonna try.